# vscode external debug window. Close windows automatically

Tags: debugging, terminal, visual-studio-code

In vscode with an external debug console (`launch.json : "console": "externalTerminal"`) the independent debug window remains open after the debug session is finished (awaiting a keypress)

It's quite practical for several reasons, for example being able to inspect the output of a previous session and eventually compare it with another.

But you have to close the older windows or you end with too many open. Has someone found a way to automatically close certain of these windows leave the x most recent? I've been trying from node.js itself listing processes and killing them, killing seems to work but the window remains visible until you press some key.